# How To Eliminate Duplicate Results?

Tags: bash, shell

I've wrote a bash script to check the /etc/fstab, fsck Option (Last column)

0 - Disable

1 - Enable**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat /etc/fstab | grep -v 'proc\|sda\|rootvg\|sysfs\|debugfs\|fd0\|.host\|nfshome:\|devpts' | awk '{print $6}') ; do
for n in $(cat /etc/fstab | grep -v 'proc\|sda\|rootvg\|sysfs\|debugfs\|fd0\|.host\|nfshome:\|devpts' | awk '{print $1}') ; do
if [[ "$i" != "0" ]] ; then
        echo "$n = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!"
else
        echo "The Non OS Partiton FSCK Complted Successfully !!!"
fi
done
done
```

Output:

```
 /dev/repovg/lvol1 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/appvg/appvol-os = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/TEST12/TEST12 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/repovg/lvol1 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/appvg/appvol-os = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/TEST12/TEST12 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/repovg/lvol1 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/appvg/appvol-os = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
/dev/TEST12/TEST12 = FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!
```

Is there any way i can eliminate the Duplicate Values.

I can try

> sh +x script.sh | Sort -u

But, is there anything I can do in the script itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a nested loop at all. Try something like this in awk:

```
awk '!/proc|sda|rootvg|sysfs|debugfs|fd0|.host|nfshome:|devpts/ {
    if ($6 != 0) print $1, "= FSCK check on NON-OS Filesystem ERROR !!!"
    else print "The Non OS Partiton FSCK Complted Successfully !!!"
}' /etc/fstab
```

This reads through `/etc/fstab` line by line, skipping lines that match the regular expression (as in your `grep`). For lines that don't match, it checks the 6th column and prints one of the two messages, depending on the value.

As an aside, the `.` in `.host` means "any character", so you should either escape it `\.` if it should mean a literal `.` or consider removing it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pipe into [`uniq`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq) after sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate all duplicates in your script you have to keep track of the values and only print out values you haven't printed already.  Piping to "sort -u" should be good enough though.

Answer (score 0):

You're combining every value in the last column with every mountpoint, that's not only giving you too many messages, but also wrong ones.

```
gawk '($NF=="0"){ print $1 }' /etc/fstab
```

should print only the 1st column of entries with a `0` in the last column, whcih puts you halfway there (with the grep you already have), without needing another loop.